# How to switch axes (x and y) of a Plotly Figure Object

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

I'm trying to create a button that allows to switch `x` and `y` axes from a `plotly.js` figure so that `x` =becomes=> `y` axis and `y` =becomes=> `x`

Reading the documentation the only thing I could find regards reversing the range using the `autorange` attribute.

Is there a way to simply switch x and y without having to create a new figure from scratch?

Comment: rotate the monitor image 90 degrees

Comment: in modele matplotlib you can replace values `xdata`, `ydata` and it should change plot (eventually it may need to run some `udpate()`). Maybe `plotly` has something similar. But when you switch `x` with `y` then `x` may have the same values many times and `x` may not accept it. Sometimes modules may have also option `orientation` to draw vertical or horizontal. Maybe plotly has something like this.

Comment: this is tagged **python** but you say **plotly.js** which is it?

Comment: Hi @RobRaymond, any of the two should be ok. My backend uses Python and my frontend uses React.

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as **python**.  Below works for flipping x & y in **python**. Similar approach could be used in javascript for structure of **updatemenus**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"var1": np.random.uniform(1, 5, 30), "var2": np.random.uniform(4, 10, 30)}
)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="var1", y="var2")

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": combi,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [
                        {"x": [fig.data[0][combi[0]]], "y": [fig.data[0][combi[1]]]}
                    ],
                }
                for combi in ["xy", "yx"]
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```